# Passing asp.net mvc model into Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, model

I am creating a web app in which, I want to pass model data into a Javascript function when user click a button,

Below is my code

```
<input type="button" id="btnNextAction" class="btn btn-primary" value="JSFunction" onclick="callJS('@Model.NextActionParam');" />
```

Javascript Function

```
function callJS(param) {

}
```

but the value of param is appears as projectName.Models.modelName.NextActionParam

> model.NextActionParam is my model which contains some properties like name, id.etc

how can I get the model property with value in Javascript?

Comment: What `Model.NextActionParam` contains?

Comment: model properties

Comment: A Javascript function can’t possibly understand a .NET object if you don’t parse it in a way that JavaScript can understand (a literal object or a JSON string).

Comment: can you please show me one example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `Model.NextActionParam` to JSON string with `Json.Encode()` method. Better way is put JSON inside `<script>` section and set some variable, then use it anywhere.

```
<script>
    var nextActionParam = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.NextActionParam));
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnNextAction" class="btn btn-primary" value="JSFunction"
onclick="callJS(nextActionParam)" />
```

Comment: Tried this but getting error,  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token `onclick="callJS('{"NextAction":null,"RegId":459405,"CurrId":0,"SurveyId":203,"SurveyType":0,"WatchParameters":"hFlkVcpTCCoI2lnA"}');" />`

Comment: If pass JSON string in attribute you need to escape `"` char. So, better replace this code in `<script>` section.